# Inserción en tabla pivote [Sequelize]

Tags: nodejs, postgresql, sequelize.js

Como puedo hacer una inserción a una tabla pivote, mandándole un arreglo.

Tengo tres tablas, una tabla que se llama categoría y tiene varios campos...

> Categoria [id, dato, dato2]

Y la siguiente tabla es de productos...

> Producto [id, dato, dato2, dato3]

Y La tabla pivote que estoy usando...

> Pivote [id, id_categoria, id_producto]

Estoy mandando un json

`{ "prod_nombre" : "Primer producto", "pord_descripcion" : "Esta es una breve descripción", "prod_usu_usuario_creado_id" : 1, "pord_cmm_estatus_id" : 1000016, "producto_categorias"   : [  7,  15 ] }`

Los producto_categorias es un arreglo que tiene los id de categorias..

Entonces al insertarlo y guardar el dato...

Normalmente se usa:

> await models.Producto.create({
> "prod_nombre" : "Primer producto",
> "pord_descripcion" : "Esta es una breve descripción",
> "prod_usu_usuario_creado_id" : 1,
> "pord_cmm_estatus_id" : 1000016,
> });

Esto guarda un registro, pero no puedo hacer que guarde la relación de 1:N

Ya lo intente de varías formas y no logro hacer que funcione, ni creando el registro primero y luego mandar el arreglo e insertarlo valor, por valor.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que se estaba mandando el arreglo, sin indicar a que pertenecen los campos...

Se enviaba como:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Y debe ser, según sus campos y según su estructura, de los modelos o tablas creadas.

MODELO PRODUCTO

```
const Producto = sequelize.define('productos', {
    prod_producto_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    prod_nombre:{
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    pord_descripcion:{
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    prod_usu_usuario_creado_id:{
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    },
    pord_cmm_estatus_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    },
    prod_usu_usuario_modificado_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW
    },
    updatedAt: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE
    }
},
{
    //Option
});
Producto.belongsTo(Usuario,{
    foreignKey : 'prod_usu_usuario_creado_id'
});
Producto.belongsTo(Usuario,{
    foreignKey : 'prod_usu_usuario_modificado_id'
});
Producto.belongsTo(ControlMestroMultiple, {
    foreignKey: 'pord_cmm_estatus_id'
});
Producto.hasMany(ProductoCategoria, { 
    foreignKey: 'prodcat_prod_producto_id' 
});
export default Producto;
```

Modelo de la tabla pivote:

```
const ProductoCategoria = sequelize.define('producto_categorias', { 
    prodcat_producto_categoria_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    prodcat_prod_producto_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    prodcat_cat_categoria_id:{
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW 
    },
    updatedAt:{
        type: Sequelize.DATE
    }
},{
    //options
});


ProductoCategoria.belongsTo(Categoria, {
    foreignKey: 'prodcat_cat_categoria_id'
});
export default ProductoCategoria;
```

Como debe quedar la petición:

```
{
"prod_nombre" : "Primer producto",
"pord_descripcion" : "Esta es una breve descripción",
"prod_usu_usuario_creado_id" : 1,
"pord_cmm_estatus_id" : 1000016,
"producto_categorias"   : [ 
     {"prodcat_cat_categoria_id" : 7}, 
  {"prodcat_cat_categoria_id": 15   }]
}
```